# Use "Solve" to convert polar to cartesian coordinates

Tags: equation-solving

I'm trying to find the Cartesian coordinates for the polar function $r=8 \cos \theta$. I'm sure there are other ways to do it; what I'm wondering is, why doesn't the below work? It just returns `{}`.

```
Solve[
 {
  r == 8 Cos[theta],
  x^2 + y^2 == r^2,
  x == r Cos[theta],
  y == r Sin[Theta]
  },
 {x, y}
 ]
```

Comment: Because `Theta` is not the same as `theta`...

Comment: And because the equations are overdetermined. Four equations for two variables...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I thought the point was to convert the equation to Cartesian coordinates. To make `Solve` work, add a list of variables to eliminate:

```
Solve[{r == 8 Cos[theta], x == r Cos[theta], 
  y == r Sin[theta]}, {y}, {r, theta}]
```

> Solve::ifun: Inverse functions are being used by Solve, so some solutions may not be found; use Reduce for complete solution information.

```
(*  {{y -> -Sqrt[8 x - x^2]}, {y -> Sqrt[8 x - x^2]}}  *)
```

Or just use `Eliminate`:

```
Eliminate[{r == 8 Cos[theta], x == r Cos[theta], y == r Sin[theta]}, {r, theta}]
```

> Eliminate::ifun: Inverse functions are being used by Eliminate, so some solutions may not be found; use Reduce for complete solution information.

```
 (*  -y^2 == -8 x + x^2  *)
```

Or perhaps:

```
TransformedField["Polar" -> "Cartesian", r == 8 Cos[theta], {r, theta} -> {x, y}]

(*  Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] == (8 x)/Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]  *)
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for!!

Comment: I did not find the "eliminate parameter list" of `Solve` in the [documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html). How do you know this?

Comment: @Qbyte https://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/v5/Built-inFunctions/AlgebraicComputation/EquationSolving/Solve.html — It’s in the old documentation. They removed it from the new documentation several versions ago, but it still works.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thank you! Is there another/official way to achieve the same elimination? As far as I know, `Eliminate` does not produce `ConditionalExpression`s.

Comment: @Qbyte `Reduce`, like `Solve`, takes a list of variables to eliminate. It won’t generate a `ConditionalExpression`, but it can generate conditions.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you use `CoordinateTransform`. You have a curve defined in polar coordinates, and you want to transform it to cartesian coordinates. Therefore:

```
cPolar[t_] := {8 Cos[t], t};
cCartesian[t_] = CoordinateTransform["Polar" -> "Cartesian", cPolar[t]]
```

which gives the coordinates $\{x,y\}$:

```
(* {8 Cos[t]^2, 8 Cos[t] Sin[t]} *)
```

Comment: This solves my problem; however, why doesn't `Solve` work? The coordinates you found satisfy the constraints I gave.

Comment: Dear @RenéG, you even do not need to use `Solve`. Equation `x^2 + y^2 == r^2` is not necessary, it is a combination of the last two. Finally, if you substitute `r` in the las two, you already have the solution I posted. Your task could be done by hand. I just only wanted to show the way of applying `CoordinateTransform` for more complex cases. You should have used instead of `Solve`, `Eliminate` as `Eliminate[{r == 8 Cos[theta], x == r Cos[theta], y == r Sin[theta]},r]`. Again you obtain the same result. Hope this helps. ;))

Answer (score 1):

Too many equations for the unknowns.  Works for

```
Solve[{r == 8 Cos[theta], x == r Cos[theta], y == r Sin[theta]}, {x, 
  y, r}];
```

or

```
Solve[{r == 8 Cos[theta], x == r Cos[theta], y == r Sin[theta]}, {x, 
  y, theta}]
```

or

```
Solve[{r == 8 Cos[theta], x^2 + y^2 == r^2, x == r Cos[theta], 
  y == r Sin[theta]}, {x, y, r, theta}];
```

although this last is pretty busy.

Comment: I think you have a typo with the capital T in the Sin

Comment: Ok, corrected.  Thanks